# If List is an abstract interface, how does Collectors.toList() work with streams?

Tags: java

I understand this will not work because List is an abstract interface:

```
List<Integer> l = new List<>();
```

and this is why I have been using typically `ArrayList<>`.

I'm curious why the following is valid in assignment of an object to `List<String> l`:

```
ArrayList<E> al = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l = al.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It was my understanding objects couldn't be created from interfaces, only when they have been implemented.  Can anyone explain why second code snippet works and how I should be understanding this difference?

Comment: Every ArrayList is a List. Therefore, the assignment is valid. What you do with it next is the point where you'll probably put it all together.

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` will give you some concrete `List` instance. Maybe an `ArrayList`, maybe something else.

Comment: Essentially for the same reason that `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` works.

Comment: in such cases you need to dig into the code you re using. the list you re getting back is obviously being generated somewhere!!

so me telling you that `Collectors.toList()` gives back "this" wont help you long-term. What i can tell you is that when you dont know how something works, you need to open the method(s) you re using and see the implementation. 

This will also help u better understand the code you re using and will make u start thinking about upgrades of libraries, backwords compatibility etc. You need to know the risks of using someone else's code. welcome to this nightmare ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collectors.toList()` will return you *some* concrete `List` instance. Maybe an `ArrayList`, maybe something else. All the API is willing to guarantee is that it conforms to the `List` interface.

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) explicitly states:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
> thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more control over the returned
> `List` is required, use [`toCollection(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-).

You can check the specific type that is returned at runtime, but shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: FYI… Seems the [implementation in OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java) for Java 21 uses `ArrayList`. But of course that may not be the case in future or past versions, or in other implementations of Java beyond OpenJDK.